# Error when trying to mount using live CD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, mount, hard-drive

I was following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/88432/528666) to resolve my boot problem and when running:

`sudo mount /dev/sdb /mnt`

I get this error:

`mount: /dev/sdb already mounted or /mnt busy`

The sdb is the drive which has 3 partitions:

```
sdb1 fat32 and the flag is set to boot
sdb2 ext4  
sdb3 linux-swap
```

am I selecting the right disk as stated in that answer?

Answer (score 0):

If your drive already has partitions with data on them you absolutely do *not* want to mount the drive.  You want to mount the partition:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt
```

Comment: so mount the boot partition or mount the ext4 ? because the answer says "Determine the partition number of your main partition" which one is the main partition?

Comment: I used `sdb1` as an example; mount whichever partition contains the data you wish to interact with.

Comment: I have installed the linux on that drive and I am worried I might remove something, so I should select `sdb2` according to the answer I posted in my question?

Comment: Given that the answer you referenced was talking about your main partition, and that in your OP it is implied that `sdb2` is where your data are, that is probably the partition you want to `mount`.  I have edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: thanks, I am in the step 7 and I get this error when I do `grub-install /dev/sdb/` : installing for x86_64-efi platform, grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory` any idea?

Comment: Comments on an answer are not a venue for this, so I will leave you with this insight:  You are again conflating _drives_ and _partitions_.